# Input utf-8 characters in management studio

Tags: unicode, utf-8

HI,

[background]
We currently build files for many different companies. Our job as a company is basically to sit in between other companies and help with communication and data storage. We have begun to run in to encoding issues where we are receiving data encoded in one format but we need to send it out in another. All files were prevsiously built using the .net framework default of UTF-8. However we've discovered that certain companies cannot read utf-8 files. I assume because they have older systems that require something else. This becomes apparent when sending certain french charaters in particular.

I have a solution in place where we can build a specific file for a specific member using a specific encoding. (While I understand that this may not be enough, unfortunately this is as far as I can go at the moment due to other issues.)

[problem]
Anyways, I'm at the testing stage and I want to input utf-8 or other characters into management studio. Perform an update on some data and then verify that the file is built correctly from that data. I realize that this is not perfect. I've already tried programatically reading the file and verifying the encoding by reading preambles etc. So this is what I'm stuck with. According to this website http://www.biega.com/special-char.html ... I can input utf-8 characters by clicking ALT+&+#+"decimal representation of character" or ALT+"decimal representation of character" but when I use the data specified by the table I get completely different characters in management studio. I've even saved the file in a utf-8 format using management studio by clicking the arrow on the save button in the save dialog and specifying the encoding. So my question is how can I accurately specify a character that will end up being the character I'm trying to input and actually put it in the data that will then be put in a file.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution. The website doesn't specify that you need to type ALT+0+"decimal character representation". The zero was left out. I'd been searching for this for ages.

Comment: Actually that doesn't even technically work. I think it only works where the characters are similar to the ones in iso8859-1 encoding or maybe it's just that in instances where I'm missing the fonts that it won't display the characters ... Does anyone know for sure?